# High "unstability" of phone internal memory

Tags: insufficient-memory, ram, system

Few days ago a problem appeared. With memory. I have phone with 8 GB internal storage and 64 GB external storage. I keep my photos, songs etc. on external storage of course. Applications are partially on internal and external memory. My phone is **Samsung Galaxy Grand Prime** powered by **Android 4.4.4 (KitKat).** **It has a root.** For a few months, free memory remained at the level of 700-600 MB. Not bad for Android. I know that the level of free memory may vary, but not as much as now. Yesterday the "diagrams of memory" began to jump on the gargantuan value. Only system memory remains the same. Used memory jumps from **~4,50 to almost 4,90 GB.** Various files....it's not worth talking. Every second value varies in the range from **43 MB** upwards. Several times the pointer took on unrealistic values ​​such as an **increase to 700 MB** without free memory shrinking, another time memory decided to multiply magically so that the values ​​of all the diagrams exceeded the total memory. Free memory jumped from 625 MB to 140 MB, next returned to ~600 MB and back to ~160 MB. Now it's varying in the range from 160 MB to 150 MB. Can I repair this without hard reset? Maybe it's a kind of memory leak and another bug.

PS. My phone doesn't slow down. And if it's necessary I can do hard reset.

Comment: And where is the problem? The flash memory is used by various apps as cache. Hence every action you make in an app may change the free space in the internal or external partition.

Comment: The problem is that I doubt that any application can reduce free space from 600 MB to 150 MB.

Comment: @BartoszKrólak Well, it has been reported that Google Play Services may take as much as 1GB, even. Still, it's unnatural and illogical for the diagrams to exceed the maximum space available. If you have a custom recovery, make a Nandroid backup, then factory reset and see if the problem sorts itself out.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen greatly inflated file sizes on the thumbnails storage file, which is a sparse file (in other words, it's not literally as large as it says it is--it's more like a reservation of maximum size).  Deleting it always fixed my issues with space, but it gets rebuilt eventually.