# Questions about safety and reversibility of SD card partitioning.

Tags: file-system, partitions

In connection with my [previous problem](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/170974/high-unstability-of-phone-internal-memory), I want to dedicate part of my memory card to the condition of the internal memory using the application Link2SD. I know that I should create a second partition "for the apps". So I have questions about the process of partitioning (to be sure that I won't break something, or I won't do something that I won't be able to reverse):

**1. To make the partitioning should I deallocate (remove) the main partition (G or another letter, NTFS logical), then create the first partition (G, Primary, FAT32), then create a second partition (Primary, ext2)?**

**2. Can I reverse the above process? By simply remove the two partitions and return to one big partition (G, NTFS logical)?**

**3. In the Android's filesystem, files from memory cards are available at the path /storage/extSdcard/. Will after partitioning the path will be still available or changed?**

**4. I have a strange path /storage/sdcard0/. For what it is responsible? Will the partitioning can change this folder?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically your approach is sound, with some minor adjustments I'd suggest:

1. You could do that. But it would be easier to simply *shrink* the existing partition. Using the right tools, that would even keep the data.
2. Of course you can, but you'd lose the data from one of the partitions: Simply remove one partition, and resize the remaining one to fill the entire card. But do NOT use NTFS :) It must be FAT then again, as it was before partitioning.
3. Depends on your device/ROM. If `/extSdcard` was, before repartitioning, the place you found the external card, after repartitioning you should find the first partition there. If not, simply use a terminal app (or `adb shell`) and issue the command `mount` (or, possibly easier, `df`) to list all mounted partitions and find where it went to. Should be the only one using FAT, so easy to tell ;)
4. That "strange path" points to your *internal* SD card. In case you wonder what then `/sdcard` is pointing to: to `/storage/sdcard0/` (it's a so-called [symlink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link)).

Comment: Thank you! That helps a lot! But what should I do if the "starting" partition is NTFS partition? Should I change to FAT32 or leave it?

Comment: You should not encounter that. NTFS normally isn't used with Android (that's a plain MS format). Android uses FAT* for external storage (SD-Card) and EXTFS for almost everything else. On some older installations you might find YAFFS, but I doubt you'd find NTFS. If you in fact do, no harm to use that afterwards as well, of course.

Answer (score 1):

I can't speak to all of your questions, but please realize that any repartitioning is 100% destructive of the data.  So, yes, you can break your single-partition SD card into two partitions, but the single-partition data will all be erased as part of the repartitioning.  Again, if you choose to combine two partitions full of data back into one all of it will be erased.  There is no non-destructive way to join them back or break them apart.  While the partition changes are completely reversable the data on those partitions will be gone unless backed up elsewhere.

I wasn't sure if you were totally aware of that from your question, so I thought it best to make sure you understand that part of things.

As far as item #4, /storage/sdcard0 is your internal storage.  It's not really an SD card at all, which can be a little confusing as to why they named it in that way.

Comment: Thanks for this answer but also I need the answer for #3. You know, I want to be sure what I'm going to do and consequences of my act.